# What causes atoms to not interact in LAMMPS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, forcefields, graphene, doping

I am trying to set up a LAMMPS simulation for depositing graphene on a nickel substrate. I am using ReaxFF forcefield. However, the carbon atoms just pass through the nickel atoms. Can anyone help me with this? This is the link to my input file:

- https://github.com/AnishD11/LAMMPS

---

````
# sample surface deposition script for atoms

units       real
atom_style      full
boundary        p p f

lattice     fcc 4.154
region          box block 0 10 0 10 0 10
create_box      2 box

region      substrate block INF INF INF INF INF 3
create_atoms    1 region substrate

pair_style  reaxff NULL
pair_coeff  * * ffield.reax.FC Ni C
fix 1 all qeq/reaxff 1 0.0 1.0 1.0e-6 reaxff
timestep 0.01
mass        1 58.7
mass            2 12.0

neigh_modify    delay 0
neigh_modify    one 1000

group       addatoms type 2
region          mobile block 0 5 0 5 2 INF
group       mobile region mobile

compute     add addatoms temp
compute_modify  add dynamic/dof yes extra/dof 0

fix     2 addatoms nve
fix     3 mobile temp/berendsen 800.0 800.0 10.0
fix     4 mobile nve

region          slab block 0 5 0 5 8 9
fix     5 addatoms deposit 100 2 100 12345 region slab near 1.0 &
                vz -1.0 -1.0
fix     6 addatoms wall/reflect zhi EDGE

thermo_style    custom step atoms temp epair etotal press
thermo          100
thermo_modify   temp add

dump        1 all atom 10 dump.deposit.atom

#dump       2 all image 50 image.*.jpg type type &
#       axes yes 0.8 0.02 view 80 -30
#dump_modify    2 pad 5

#dump       3 all movie 50 movie.mpg type type &
#       axes yes 0.8 0.02 view 80 -30
#dump_modify    3 pad 5

run             1000
```
````

Comment: +1 but why not add your input file so that people can see what you tried?

Comment: I have added the link to my input file.

Comment: @NikeDattani Anish has done so

Comment: Thanks for the update @Anish! From [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080)

Comment: You have created substrate (type 1) "create_atoms    1 region substrate".which line you are introducing graphene?

Comment: I suspect something might be wrong with the `* * ffield.reax.FC Ni C` file. Are the atomic radii correct and in real units:
```
10    ! Nr of atoms; cov.r ...                                         
 C    1.3831 ...
```